# Silex валидация

Tags: php, symfony, валидация, silex

Пишу RestApi на фреймворке silex. Понял, что слишком много условий перед выполнением действий. Проверяю переменные на пустоту, наличие переданных id в базе данных и прочее.

В yii2 очень удобная валидация с помощью функции rules. Есть ли что то подобное для Silex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В silex есть [встроенный провайдер](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/master/providers/validator.html) для [компонента симфони валидации](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html).

Comment: Не подскажете как применить несколько правил к одному элементу коллекции?

Comment: Просто в массиве перечислить все ограничения, которые нужны, например: array(new Assert\NotBlank(), new Assert\Length(array('min' => 10)))

Answer (score 0):

Нашел неплохой валидатор https://github.com/Respect/Validation Попробую пока что использовать его.